# Gui isn't showing images in Tkinter GUI

Tags: python, tkinter

My code:

```
import tkinter
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

articles=[]
images=[]

for filename in os.listdir('resources'):
    if filename.endswith('.txt'):
        articles.append(filename)
    if filename.endswith('.png'):
        images.append(filename)
        
root=tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')

for i in range(len(images)):
    path=os.path.join('resources',images[i])
    image_file = tkinter.PhotoImage(file=path)
    tkinter.Label(image=image_file).pack()
    
    path=os.path.join('resources',articles[i])
    file1=open(path)
    tkinter.Label(text=file1.read()).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Resources Used: A director named resources stored in same directory as the program file containing images in PNG format and correspondingly a .txt file e.g 1.png has a 1.txt.

IDE: Visual Studios Code

Error: The window leaves space required to fill the image but image doesn't appear. I tried the same code with other images that I know will load but same error occurs, I tried using these images in another GUI, there they loaded without error.

Required Output: The images should appear followed by corresponding text article beneath them.

Current Output: Spaces are left where images should appear but text prints fine.

Comment: You aren't saving a reference to the images, so they get garbage-collected immediately.  (Passing the image to a widget just stores the internal name of the image, it doesn't count as a reference.)

Answer (score 0):

As @jasonharper said, your images are being garbage collected because there is no reference to them. To avoid that, try something like this in your for loop:

```
image_file = tkinter.PhotoImage(file=path)
lab = tkinter.Label(image=image_file)
lab.img = image_file
lab.pack()
```

`lab.img = image_file` creates a reference to the image, so it is therefore not garbage collected.